# Problem opening spacemacs on mac OS Sierra when clicking spacemacs icon.

Tags: spacemacs, osx, emacsclient

trying to install `spacemacs` using the **Alternate installation** [instructions](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#macos), but when I load the app using the app icon on the `Applications` folder I get the following.

**TL;DR:** How to link `env HOME=$HOME/spacemacs emacs` command to the spacemacs icon.

[image]

But when I actually use the command `env HOME=$HOME/spacemacs emacs` I get it to open. Did I miss something?

**PS:** for someone coming from sublime what is the best editing style to choose: `vim` or `emacs`?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I guess you found the answers to these questions by now. If not: Try closing and restarting emacs a couple of times. I recommend you use the Vim editing style. Enjoy!